# Checking the available .NET framework on a client using C++

Tags: .net, c++, windows

Is there a way to check and see what version of the .NET framework is available on a machine, without manually digging through the registry, etc.?

Ideally, from C++. How can this be solved it?

Comment: This KB article does a pretty good job of explaining the process. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914135

Comment: What is this for? There are typically ways to automate this with installers and the like.

Comment: Digging through the registry is *exactly* what is required to get this info.  Trying to avoid this is pointless.

Comment: Im assuming the OP wants an un managed library for .net detection.

Answer (score 1):

Check registry

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP
```