# Detecting .NET Framework on Windows

Tags: .net, c++, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect what .NET Framework versions and service packs are installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199080)
>   [Checking the available .NET framework on a client using C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564666)

Is there a deterministic and straightforward way to detect if a certain version (or higher) of the .NET Framework is installed on a Windows machine without using the .NET Framework itself?

How would one go about implementing it?

Example code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your code could check the name of the subdirectories of `c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework`. Those directories the name of which starts with a `v` contain installed versions of the .NET framework. Example:

```
v1.0.3705
v1.1.4322
v2.0.50727
v3.0
v3.5
v4.0.30319
```